# java timer will not work

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to set an int, defined in the class, to 0, 5 seconds after it has been changed to more than 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have a program where users have to input an addition to a score.

```
private void inputResponse(int pNum) {
    Patient p = null;
    p = patientList.get(pNum);
    Map<String, List<Double>> pData = sEWSTracker.get(p);
    List<Double> sEp = pData.get("SEW");
    Double sEWS = sEp.get(sEp.size() - 1);

    Component frame = null;

    Object[] response = {"Alert", "Verbal", "Pain", "Unresponsive"};
    String r = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Please input the patient’s response external stimulus:\n", "Please Report Patient's Response Level",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
            response, response[0]);

    int reACT = 0;

    if (r.equals("Verbal")) {

        if (pNum == 0) {
            p0checked = 1;
        }
        if (pNum == 1) {
            p1checked = 1;
        }
        if (pNum == 2) {
            p2checked = 1;
        }
        if (pNum == 3) {
            p3checked = 1;
        }
        if (pNum == 4) {
            p4checked = 1;
        }
        if (pNum == 4) {
            p5checked = 1;
        }

    }
    if (r.equals("Pain")) {

        if (pNum == 0) {
            p0checked = 2;
        }
        if (pNum == 1) {
            p1checked = 2;
        }
        if (pNum == 2) {
            p2checked = 2;
        }
        if (pNum == 3) {
            p3checked = 2;
        }
        if (pNum == 4) {
            p4checked = 2;
        }
        if (pNum == 4) {
            p5checked = 2;
        }

    }
    if (r.equals("Unresponsive")) {

        if (pNum == 0) {
            p0checked = 3;
        }
        if (pNum == 1) {
            p1checked = 3;
        }
        if (pNum == 2) {
            p2checked = 3;
        }
        if (pNum == 3) {
            p3checked = 3;
        }
        if (pNum == 4) {
            p4checked = 3;
        }
        if (pNum == 4) {
            p5checked = 3;
        }

    }

    Double sEWP = (reACT * 1.0) + sEWS;
    List<Double> soEWS = pData.get("SEW");
    soEWS.add(sEWP);

    this.repaint();
    sEWSreact(pNum);

}
```

Until they do the representation has a little message on it saying "Partial Score":

(for example)

```
if (p0checked == 0) {

    g2.setColor(darkOrange);
    g2.fillRoundRect(250, 152, 120, 35, 10, 10);
    g2.setColor(mellowOrange);
    g2.fillRoundRect(252, 154, 116, 31, 10, 10);
    g2.setColor(darkBlue);
    g2.setFont(helvetica1);
    g2.drawString("Partial", 272, 170);
    g2.setFont(verdanda4);
    g2.setColor(Color.white);
    g2.drawString("Click here to update", 258, 182);
}
}
```

And then a timer that resets the additional score to 0, in order to make the partial score notice come back and the score go back down to the original. ...however, nothing happens

```
if (p0checked > 0) {
    Timer tim = new Timer(5 * 1000, new ActionListener() {@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timSec >= 1) {
                p0checked = 0;
            }
            timSec++;
        }
    });
    tim.start();
}
```

timSec is defined (as 0) in the class also.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: May your program exits premature? Try to run your code in a seperate thread an see if things change.

Comment: @MadProgrammer hey, i have added more information that may help :)

Comment: Try calling `repaint` at the end of the `actionPerformed` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer didn't work :(

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: hang on... can you have more than one timer or overriden action Performed?